# Skip() vs Skipwhile() in Linq

Tags: .net, linq

What is the difference between Skip() and SkipWhile() extension methods in Linq?

Comment: Have your tried to read msdn?

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-23-take-skip-takewhile-skipwhile.aspx

Comment: [How to Use Take/TakeWhile and Skip/SkipWhile in LINQ](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dbd951/how-to-use-taketakewhile-and-skipskipwhile-in-linq/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip specifies a number of items to skip.

```
 myList.Skip(10)
```

SkipWhile allows you to supply a predicate function to determine how many to skip.

```
myList.SkipWhile(x => x.Age < 18)
```

`Skip` Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx

`SkipWhile` Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx

Answer (score 4):

**SKIP**

`Skip()` will take an integer argument and skips the top n numbers from the given `IEnumerable`

*example*

```
yourlist.Skip(5)
```

the above line of code will skip`5` rows from the top in any collection

**SkipWhile**

`SkipWhile()` continues to skip the elements as long as the input condition is true. Once condition turns false it will return all remaining elements.

*example*

```
yourList.SkipWhile(x => x.marks < 50)
```

the above line of code will skip until the condition `marks < 50` is true

[Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [SkipWhile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx) according to MSDN

Comment: then what is the difference between where and skipwhile.